# Do all queries run within a single Django request operate on the same DB snapshot?

Tags: database, django, transactions, consistency

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) on transaction management focuses on write operations. I'm puzzled what guarantees Django gives on read consistency. If one request executes multiple read queries, and the second request writes to a database between these queries, is there a guarantee that the first request won't see the modifications?

To illustrate the question with a simple example:

```
c1 = select count(*) from Users
   <--- here User added by some other request
c2 = select count(*) from Users
assert c1 == c2 <-- Is this always true?
```

If there is no such guarantee, is it possible to achieve such isolation?

Comment: Good question, I wanna know that too now that you said it.

Answer (score 0):

Django isn't in the business of guaranteeing these things: it's up to the database. But Django does, by default, operate each request within its own transaction, which does mean that it is isolated for reads.